# onClick does not work properly on p tag

Tags: javascript, onclick

I want to bind a click event to every `<p>` but it does not seem to work properly.

When I run the script I instantly get three alerts. I only want to get them when clicking any of the three `<p>'`s.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Edit: Sry this is what it looks like.
The HTML is just as it should: `<p class="special">text text text</p>` etc

```
(function () {
    var myFunction = function (theP) {
            alert(theP.id)          
        }


    window.onload = function () {           
        var pTags = document.getElementsByTagName('p'),
            pLength = pTags.length,
            i;

        for (i = 0; i < pLength; i += 1) {
            if(pTags[i].className == 'special'){

                pTags[i].onClick = myFunction(pTags[i]);

            }
        };
    }
})();
```

Ps. I cannot use jQuery atm

Comment: Can we see a snippet of your html?  You don't have nested p tags do you?

Comment: Once you fix the function issue mentioned by scraimer, this code will still not work in all browsers. Consider binding with the approach shown at http://www.quirksmode.org/js/eventSimple.html.

Comment: @ Alan, i edited my post see ^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all answers. Much appreciated!
I rewrote my own script and solved it like this:
How does that look?

```
(function () {
    var myFunction1 = function (theP) {
            theP.onclick = myFunction2;
        },

        myFunction2 = function(){
            alert('hello world')
        }


    window.onload = function () {           
        var pTags = document.getElementsByTagName('p'),
            pLength = pTags.length,
            i;

        for (i = 0; i < pLength; i += 1) {
            if(pTags[i].className == 'special'){
                myFunction1(pTags[i]);
            }
        }
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 7):

Try replacing

```
pTags[i].onClick = myFunction(pTags[i]);
```

with

```
pTags[i].onClick = function() { myFunction(pTags[i]); }
```

You see, when you assign to the `onClick` of an object, you're copying the result of the expression to it. What your supposed to copy is a function to call when the `p` is clicked.

Instead, you're **running** the command `myFunction(pTags[i])`, which executes the `alert()`s, and takes the result of the function. Now, since the function doesn't return anything, the value of the expression `myFunction(pTags[i])` is undefined.

And you take that value, and assign it to `onClick`. So basically what you've done is:

For each "special" paragraph:

1. Execute `alert`
2. Assign `undefined` to the paragraph's `onClick`.

Comment: Exactly.  What you've done is assigned the click event to a call to a function (i.e. call the function now, and assign the result to the event).  What you want is to actually assign the event to a function.

Answer (score 4):

myFunction would need to return a function for your code to work

Below someone mentions an option that tries to create an inline function, but because closure binding happens with variables, not values, this will not work  (The `i` in the code will be modified after including it in the function).

There are two obvious ways to create the function and have it work.  One is to create a per-handler function... The other is using `this` to get the element.

```
(function () {
    var myFunction = function (theP) {
            return function() {
                alert(theP.id);
            }                 
        }


    window.onload = function () {                       
        var pTags = document.getElementsByTagName('p'),
                pLength = pTags.length,
                i;

        for (i = 0; i < pLength; i += 1) {
                if(pTags[i].className == 'special'){

                        pTags[i].onClick = myFunction(pTags[i]);

                }
        };
    }
})();
```

And with `this`

```
(function () {
    var myFunction = function () {
                alert(this.id)                  
        }


    window.onload = function () {                       
        var pTags = document.getElementsByTagName('p'),
                pLength = pTags.length,
                i;

        for (i = 0; i < pLength; i += 1) {
                if(pTags[i].className == 'special'){

                        pTags[i].onClick = myFunction;

                }
        };
    }
})();
```

The second format is the preferred format, as it uses much less memory to implement by the browser.

Comment: thanks for that! 
i changed my code since i typed in the wrong thing.
myFunction is declared as 'var myFunction = function(theP) {..}'

Answer (score 4):

**.onclick** is case sensitive, isn't it?

Comment: btw, just tested, `onClick` does not work on Chrome Latest,Opera 10, Firefox3.7, and IE8. only `onclick` works

Comment: all people using `onClick` as examples, so I am quite shocked that I did big misunderstanding in my life or not, fortunately Its not. :P

Answer (score 1):

You are calling your function.  When you use the parenthesis you call your function.

onclick requires a function reference:

You could modify your code this way:

```
myFunction(theP){
 return function(){alert(theP.id)};
}
```

This would insure that your call returns a function reference instead of a value.