# How to put 2 onchange=" " in <select>

Tags: javascript

I have a select option tag and i would like to put two onchange="" in the same tag but when i choose an option, it only work for: onChange="window.location.href=this.value" --> Show selected option on the url

But it did not work for: onchange="sortResult(this.value)".

If this is not allowed, then how can I achieve this?

```
<select name="sortby" class="form-control" id="city" onChange="window.location.href=this.value" onchange="sortResult(this.value)">
 <option>1</option>
 <option>2</option>
 ...
</select>
```

Comment: using `;` symbol: `onChange="window.location.href=this.value;sortResult(this.value)"`

Comment: Even better, use `addEventListener`

Comment: If you are redirecting the page, `sortResult()` will be useless

Answer (score 1):

Just use semicolon to separate it:

```
onChange="window.location.href=this.value; sortResult(this.value)"
```

So your HTML will read as:

```
<select name="sortby" class="form-control" id="city" onChange="window.location.href=this.value; sortResult(this.value)">
 <option>1</option>
 <option>2</option>
 ...
</select>
```

If you wish to manipulate the part of URL which is after hashtag #, use `location.hash=this.value` instead of `location.href`

Comment: By the way, what you are trying to do is somehow strange. Setting window.location.href to some value will effectively load a new webpage in your browser so there is no reason to sortResult() later...

Comment: adding a hashtag doesn't reload the page.

Answer (score 1):

Better avoid event handler content attributes and add the event handler using `addEventListener`:

```js
document.getElementById('city').addEventListener('change', function() {
    window.location.href = this.value;
    sortResult(this.value);
});
```

However, if you change `window.location.href`, you will unload the page, so `sortResult` may not be called.

Comment: why do you think that avoiding event handler content attributes is better? It's a matter of taste, nothing more.

Comment: @TomasMatejicek It's called [Separation of Concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). In the same way that [presentation should be separated from content](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_presentation_and_content), behavior should too. Moreover, if you use event handler content attributes, the functions you want to call must be global. And the scope in those handlers behaves weird, so properties from `Element.prototype` can shadow the function you want to call (see [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28174022/1529630)).

Comment: Pointing out a problem in the post: the suggestion of avoiding event handler content attributes may be inappropriate. Although addEventListener matches the use case, it very much is not a replacement for event handler content attributes.