# Various custom variable names like createComment get overriden in inline javascript but not in external js. Why?

Tags: javascript, variables, scope

I have code like

```
<div id="loadCommentBestComment" style="cursor:pointer" onclick="createComment('af0532_$dvkpo6420')">load the most useful comment.</div>
```

The problem was that I was clicking on it and nothing was executing, the function createComment() wasn't even being called.
 hours tried to figure out what was going on but nothing. Then tried to change the name of createComment to another name like createCommentAlias() and everything worked fine.
 this is not the first time this happens, I have gotten weird behaviours of this kind previously as well. and again due to variable names which seemingly were overriden by other native variables.
Another example, the name nextSibling is a method of a Dom element, and thus can normally be used as var nextSibling, but in inline js it gets, again, overriden by something else. And again this happens only if the js is inline.
 So I'd like to know what are these variable, where do they come from, and possibly have a list of them so that I don't use those names again.

Comment: Related: [JS function named `animate` doesn't work in Chrome, but works in IE](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28173800/1529630).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that, since you use an [event handler content attribute](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#event-handler-content-attributes), your global function...

```js
window.createComment
```

...is shadowed by...

```js
Document.prototype.createComment
```

This behavior is explained in [step 10](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#event-handler-attributes:script-execution-environment-2) of [getting the current value of the event handler](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#getting-the-current-value-of-the-event-handler):

> **Lexical Environment Scope**
>
> 1. If *H* is an element's [event handler](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#event-handlers), then let *Scope* be the result of NewObjectEnvironment(*document*, the *global environment*).
>
>    Otherwise, *H* is a [`Window`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#window) object's [event handler](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#event-handlers): let
>      *Scope* be the *global environment*.
> 2. If *form owner* is not null, let *Scope* be the result of NewObjectEnvironment(*form owner*, *Scope*).
> 3. If *element* is not null, let *Scope* be the result of NewObjectEnvironment(*element, Scope*).
>
> Note: *NewObjectEnvironment() is defined in ECMAScript edition 5 section [10.2.2.3 NewObjectEnvironment (O, E)](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.2.2.3)*

That means that the global scope is shadowed by

1. The document
2. The form owner, if any
3. The element

Therefore, you can

- Rename your function

  ```js
  function createComment__() {
    var div = document.getElementById('loadComment');
    div.style.left = "200px";
    div.style.color = "red";
  }
  ```

  ```css
  #loadComment {
    position: absolute;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <p id="loadComment" onclick="createComment__()">lolol</p>
  ```
- Use `window.createComment` (assuming `window` is not shadowed):

  ```html
  <p id="loadComment" onclick="window.createComment()">lolol</p>
  ```

  ```js
  function createComment() {
    var div = document.getElementById('loadComment');
    div.style.left = "200px";
    div.style.color = "red";
  }
  ```

  ```css
  #loadComment {
    position: absolute;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <p id="loadComment" onclick="window.createComment()">lolol</p>
  ```
- Avoid event handlers content attributes:

  ```js
  document.getElementById('loadComment').onclick = createComment;
  ```

  ```js
  function createComment() {
    var div = document.getElementById('loadComment');
    div.style.left = "200px";
    div.style.color = "red";
  }
  document.getElementById('loadComment').onclick = createComment;
  ```

  ```css
  #loadComment {
    position: absolute;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <p id="loadComment">lolol</p>
  ```

The only safe approach is the third one, because you can't be sure if some browsers implement a non-standard feature which shadows your variables. Or a future spec could introduce that feature (see [example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28173800/1529630)).