# JavaScript animations movement

Tags: javascript, animation

I am trying to make an animation in JavaScript, but there is an error i cannot find because my code won't work. I am trying to get the blue box to move diagonally from left to right but it just stays still. Please help.

```js
function animate() {
  var elem = document.getElementById('ani');
  var pos = 0;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 3);

  function frame() {
    if (pos == 350) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      pos++;
      elem.style.top = pos + "px";
      elem.style.left = pos + "px";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#box {
  background: red;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
}

#ani {
  background: blue;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css' />
  <script src='script.js'></script>
  <title>Practice</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p>
    <button onclick="animate()">OK</button>
  </p>
  <div id="box">
    <div id="ani"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use different function name than `animate`. [[Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28173800/js-function-named-animate-doesnt-work-in-chrome-but-works-in-ie)]

> The `Element.animate()` method is a shortcut method for creating and playing an animation on an element. And when `global function` `animate()` is declared, it is **`shadowed`** by `Element.prototype.animate`

Try this:

```js
function animateMe() {
  var elem = document.getElementById('ani');
  var pos = 0;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 3);

  function frame() {
    if (pos == 350) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      pos++;
      elem.style.top = pos + "px";
      elem.style.left = pos + "px";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
 #box {
   background: red;
   width: 400px;
   height: 400px;
   position: relative;
 }
 #ani {
   background: blue;
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   position: absolute;
 }
```

```html
<p>
  <button onclick="animateMe()">OK</button>
</p>
<div id="box">
  <div id="ani"></div>
</div>
```

**Note:** As explained in the provided reference, you can use `window.animate()` as it will not refer to `shadowed` prototype but `Global animate function`

[**Fiddle here**](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/kv3ywggc/1/)