# Uncaught TypeError: lang is not a function

Tags: javascript, typeerror

In my HTML I define the `lang` function in the `script` tag and add the "Test Fire!" button which has to call `lang` on click:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Testing Functions</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function lang() {
      alert("Hello, World! It's JavaScript this time");
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <form action="">
    <input type="button" value="Test Fire!" onclick="lang();">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

However, if I click the button I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: `lang` is not a function

But if I change the function name from `lang` to anything else this code works fine.

Comment: interesting... check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/h4m1qcoq/   it calls the function through JS, which succeeds, but fails on the click.

Comment: I'm interested in seeing the outcome of this one because that is an interesting issue.

Comment: It seems this is a problem with the `onclick` attribute. It works fine assigning the onclick even via JS: `document.getElementById('foo').onclick = lang`.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek Though I did not try, I thought that would be the case here - thank you for verifying. I did find out that changing the method name _doesn't_ help -- according to JSFiddle.

Comment: Could it be a browser based issue?

Comment: @RichardBarker Yes, works in IE but not Chrome.

Comment: Check this: https://jsfiddle.net/cmedina/h4m1qcoq/6/ It's working!

Comment: @CMedina while that does what the OP is looking to do, it fails to actually solve the issue.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek then there it is. Its chrome's implementation of the EMACS (i think its called) spec. Someone post a bug report to their tracker.

Comment: @RichardBarker EMACS is something completely different. It’s called ECMAScript. It’s also not only happening in Chrome, but also in Firefox.

Comment: Same as [JS function named `animate` doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28173800/1529630), but with `lang` instead of `animate`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider this code:

```html
<input type="button" value="Debugger Test" onclick="debugger;" />
<input type="button" value="Prototype Test" onclick="console.log(__proto__);" />
```

When you click on “Debugger Test” and open your debugger, you’ll see that there seems to be an implicit `with` scope wrapped around the `onclick`, making all the `<input>`’s properties accessible without needing to refer to the button.

Clicking on “Prototype Test” logs the prototype of the current scope. You’ll see that it’s the `HTMLInputElement`’s prototype, making all the [scopable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/unscopables) properties of this entire prototype chain available to the scope.

Interestingly, the scopable part of the prototype chain of the current `HTMLDocument` is included as well.

All this means that all global attributes (`lang` is one of them) and several others specific to buttons are overridden. E.g. `value`, `type` also wouldn’t work. Similarly, variables like `createElement` (from `document`) also wouldn’t work, but the unscopable `append` (from `ParentNode.prototype`) would.

All this is also explained in this [answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51062916/4642212) about global variables clashing with `window` properties.

---

Your best bet is to use the standard way of adding event listeners: [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#Inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_don't_use_these).

```html
<input type="button" value="Test" />
<script>
  function lang() {
    alert("Hello, World! It’s not an HTML event handler attribute this time");
  }

  document.querySelector("input").addEventListener("click", lang);
</script>
```

Comment: So I'm assuming both Firefox and Chrome have this `with` scope, while IE does not?

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek This seems to be the case for these three browsers. This issue is also new to me. I’m not sure whether this is a specified and documented feature… For Firefox at least, this doesn’t seem to be related to quirks mode.

Comment: Somehow IE managed to make this code run. Any clues why so?

Comment: @SanyamMishra Well, IE apparently does not wrap the code in the `onclick` in an implicit `with` scope as opposed to the other browsers.

Comment: @Xufox any idea of a workaround?

Comment: @RichardBarker Haven’t I written that in my answer? Use `addEventListener`! Or use any function name that isn’t a global attribute or any attribute or property name for the element you’re using `onclick` with (good luck guessing each time). Just stick to the modern standard (`addEventListener`) and you’ll generally have less trouble.

Comment: Yes but I was speaking of the `with` issue not the event listener. that seems like a bug to me but it could be a design decision.

Comment: @RichardBarker Well, this is browser-specific behavior. There doesn’t seem to be any way of overriding that.

Comment: @RichardBarker It's very likely a design decision. Using the `onclick` attribute is discouraged anyways.

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason to complicate (*I really do not know why it does not work*), but you can use:

- Add the alert directly in the input.

Result: https://jsfiddle.net/cmedina/h4m1qcoq/6/

**or**

Add listener to input

```
function lang() {
   alert("Hello, World! It's JavaScript this time");
}

document.getElementById('test').onclick = lang
```

Result: https://jsfiddle.net/cmedina/h4m1qcoq/7/

Comment: My purpose here is not to generate an alert. I just illustrated that calling "lang()" isn't working.

Comment: @SanyamMishra then add listener to button my second option!