# Scope changes during HTML parsing

Tags: html, dom, scope

If you create a form in HTML like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
<script>
function submit() {
    console.log("window.submit");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="form">
    <input type="button" value="button" onclick="submit()" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

When the `input` tag is parsed (in chrome at least), the corresponding DOM element will apparently be created with the form as the scope, so that the function bound to the onclick handler will be `form.submit()` rather than `window.submit()`.  Is this standard behavior or browser dependent?  Is there any documentation that covers this?

Comment: Could be related to [Uncaught TypeError: lang is not a function](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38276407/4642212).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WHATWG HTML Standard defines it in Event Handler Attributes
https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#event-handler-attributes

> Scope
>
> ```
>     - If H is an element's event handler, then let Scope 
>     be NewObjectEnvironment(document, the global environment).
>     - Otherwise, H is a Window object's event handler: let Scope be the global environment.
>     - If form owner is not null, let Scope be NewObjectEnvironment(form owner, Scope).
>     - If element is not null, let Scope be NewObjectEnvironment(element, Scope).
> ```

In this case, since  form owner is not null, every property of the Form will be in the scope. "submit" is a property of form, so "submit()" will call form.submit().

Comment: Almost the same definition in https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#event-handler-attributes at step 10 "Lexical Environment Scope"