# Checked is not a function javascript error

Tags: javascript, html, function, onclick, syntax-error

I am working on a simple To-Do list project. In this project you are able to add a task and once the user presses submit the task is shown along with a checkbox. When you click the `checkbox`, it's supposed to show an `alert` and make the tasks `style` decoration `line-through`.

I've tried many ways to accomplish this. The first way I tried work however it only worked on one task and for the others, it showed an error. I also tried making it work with an if statement but it's just showing the same error. I've tried switching a lot of things around (that's why my code looks so messy) but it just won't work.

```js
var name = prompt("Please Enter Your Name :)");
document.write('<h1 id = "greet">' + 'Hello  ' + name + ' Let\'s Be Productive Today' + '</h1>');

function showTime() {
  var date = new Date();
  var h = date.getHours();
  var m = date.getMinutes();
  var s = date.getSeconds();
  var session = "AM";

  if (h == 0) {
    h = 12;
  }

  if (h > 12) {
    h = h - 12;
    session = "PM";
  }

  h = (h < 10) ? "0" + h : h;
  m = (m < 10) ? "0" + m : m;
  s = (s < 10) ? "0" + s : s;

  var time = h + ":" + m + ":" + s + " " + session;
  document.getElementById("MyClockDisplay").innerText = time;
  document.getElementById("MyClockDisplay").textContent = time;

  setTimeout(showTime, 1000);

}

showTime();
document.getElementById("b").onclick = function () {
  document.querySelector(".To-Do").style.display = 'flex';
}
document.querySelector(".close").onclick = function () {
  document.querySelector(".To-Do").style.display = 'none';
}

document.getElementById("task");
document.getElementById("date");
document.getElementById("tsks");
document.getElementById("check");

document.getElementById("s").onclick = function () {
  var newEl = document.createElement("p");
  newEl.setAttribute("id", "tsks");
  newEl.innerHTML = "<input type = 'checkbox' id = 'check' onclick = 'checked();'>" + task.value + ' ' + date.value;
  document.getElementById('task2').appendChild(newEl);


}

function checked() {
  if (check.onclick == true) {
    tsks.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
    alert("You completed task" + tsks.value + "Good Job!");
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/dLrp1gP/43150024-polka-dot-background-blue-vector-elegant-image.jpg");
}

.content {
  background-color: white;
  width: 700px;
  height: 400px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 325px;
  top: 150px;
}

#greet {
  position: absolute;
  left: 445px;
  top: 150px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#2980B9, #6DD5FA, #fff);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

#MyClockDisplay {
  color: blue;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  left: 625px;
  top: 230px;
}

#b {
  background-image: linear-gradient(#2980B9, #6DD5FA, #fff);
  color: black;
  border-color: white;
  text-weight: bold;
  width: 70px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 625px;
  top: 260px;
}

.To-Do {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: none;
  z-index: 1;
}

.modal-content {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: purple;
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 14px;
  font-size: 32px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  cursor: pointer;
}

#aat {
  background-color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}

h2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 590px;
  top: 305px;
  border-bottom: 5px solid blue;
}

p {
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
  left: 590px;
  top: 360px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
<title>To-Do List</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class = "content"></div>
    <div id="MyClockDisplay" class="clock" onload="showTime()"></div>
    <button id = "b">Add A Task</button>
    <div class = "To-Do">
      <div class = "modal-content">
        <h1 align = "center" id = "aat">ADD A TASK</h1>
        <input type = "text" placeholder = "task" id = "task">
        <input type = "date" id = "date">
        <div class = "close">+</div>
        <input type = "submit" id = "s">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id = "task2"></div>
    <h2>YOUR TASKS</h2>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don’t use `onclick` or use a function name other than `checked`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JS function named \`animate\` doesn't work in Chrome, but works in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28173800/js-function-named-animate-doesnt-work-in-chrome-but-works-in-ie) and [Uncaught TypeError: lang is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38276407/4642212). Finally found that dupe…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey it worked by changing  **if(check.onclick == true)** to i**f(check.checked == true)** and also function name from checked to chec, because **checked** is a property in java script . So this keyword cannot be used as function name.

```js
var name = prompt("Please Enter Your Name :)");
document.write( '<h1 id = "greet">' + 'Hello  ' + name + ' Let\'s Be Productive Today' + '</h1>');
function showTime(){
    var date = new Date();
    var h = date.getHours(); 
    var m = date.getMinutes(); 
    var s = date.getSeconds();
    var session = "AM";
    
    if(h == 0){
        h = 12;
    }
    
    if(h > 12){
        h = h - 12;
        session = "PM";
    }
    
    h = (h < 10) ? "0" + h : h;
    m = (m < 10) ? "0" + m : m;
    s = (s < 10) ? "0" + s : s;
    
    var time = h + ":" + m + ":" + s + " " + session;
    document.getElementById("MyClockDisplay").innerText = time;
    document.getElementById("MyClockDisplay").textContent = time;
    
    setTimeout(showTime, 1000);
    
}

showTime();
document.getElementById("b").onclick = function() {
 document.querySelector(".To-Do").style.display = 'flex';
}
document.querySelector(".close").onclick = function() {
 document.querySelector(".To-Do").style.display = 'none';
}

document.getElementById("task");
document.getElementById("date");
document.getElementById("tsks");
document.getElementById("check");

document.getElementById("s").onclick = function() {
 var newEl = document.createElement("p");
 newEl.setAttribute("id", "tsks" );
     newEl.innerHTML =  "<input type = 'checkbox' id = 'check' onclick = 'chec()'>"  + task.value  + '&nbsp;' + date.value;
 document.getElementById('task2').appendChild(newEl);


}
function chec() {
 if(check.checked == true) {
  tsks.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
 alert("You completed task" + tsks.value + "Good Job!");
 }
}
```

```css
body {
  background-image:url("https://i.ibb.co/dLrp1gP/43150024-polka-dot-background-blue-vector-elegant-image.jpg");
 }
 .content {
  background-color:white;
  width:700px;
  height:400px;
  position:absolute;
  left:325px;
  top:150px;
 }
 #greet {
  position:absolute;
  left:445px;
  top:150px;
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#2980B9, #6DD5FA, #fff);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
 }
 #MyClockDisplay {
  color:blue;
  font-weight:bold;
  position:absolute;
  left:625px;
  top:230px;
 }
 #b {
  background-image:linear-gradient(#2980B9, #6DD5FA, #fff);
  color:black;
  border-color:white;
  text-weight:bold;
  width:70px;
  height:50px;
  position:absolute;
  left:625px;
  top:260px;
 }
 .To-Do {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  display:none;
  z-index:1;
  

  
 }
 .modal-content {
  width:500px;
  height:300px;
  border-radius:10px;
  position:relative;
  background-color:purple;
 }
 .close {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:14px;
  font-size:32px;
  transform:rotate(45deg);
  cursor:pointer;

 }
 #aat {
  background-color:white;
  font-weight:bold;
 }

 h2 {
  position:absolute;
  left:590px;
  top:305px;
  border-bottom:5px solid blue;
 }
 p {
  font-weight:bold;
  position:relative;
  left:590px;
  top:360px;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>To-Do List</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class = "content"></div>
<div id="MyClockDisplay" class="clock" onload="showTime()"></div>
<button id = "b">Add A Task</button>
<div class = "To-Do">
<div class = "modal-content">
<h1 align = "center" id = "aat">ADD A TASK</h1>
<input type = "text" placeholder = "task" id = "task">
<input type = "date" id = "date">
<div class = "close">+</div>
<input type = "submit" id = "s">
</div>
</div>
<div id = "task2"></div>
<h2>YOUR TASKS</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: _“because `checked` is a property in JavaScript”_ — what? That’s absolutely not why it doesn’t work. It doesn’t work because the `onclick` attribute assumes an implicit `with`-scope that includes the element’s prototype which contains the boolean getter property `checked` from `HTMLInputElement.prototype.checked`, overriding the `checked` function defined above. Which, by the way, is one of [_many_ reasons to avoid `onclick`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43459991/4642212).

Comment: Also, it’s not a keyword.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why, but within the scope of the `onclick` execution, `checked` is a local variable that contains the checkbox's `clicked` property.

There are several ways you can resolve this:

1. Rename the function so it doesn't conflict with this variable.
2. Call it as `window.checked()`.
3. Assign the handler by assigning to the `onclick` property or calling `addEventListener` rather than putting it in the HTML.

I've chosen the last method.

Also, IDs should be unique, you can't reuse the IDs `check` and `tsks` for every task. You can refer to the box that was clicked on with `this` in the function, and the containing `p` element with `this.parentElement`.

A `p` element doesn't have a `value` property, use `textContent` to get the name of the task.

```js
var name = prompt("Please Enter Your Name :)");
document.write('<h1 id = "greet">' + 'Hello  ' + name + ' Let\'s Be Productive Today' + '</h1>');

function showTime() {
  var date = new Date();
  var h = date.getHours();
  var m = date.getMinutes();
  var s = date.getSeconds();
  var session = "AM";

  if (h == 0) {
    h = 12;
  }

  if (h > 12) {
    h = h - 12;
    session = "PM";
  }

  h = (h < 10) ? "0" + h : h;
  m = (m < 10) ? "0" + m : m;
  s = (s < 10) ? "0" + s : s;

  var time = h + ":" + m + ":" + s + " " + session;
  document.getElementById("MyClockDisplay").innerText = time;
  document.getElementById("MyClockDisplay").textContent = time;

  setTimeout(showTime, 1000);

}

showTime();
document.getElementById("b").onclick = function () {
  document.querySelector(".To-Do").style.display = 'flex';
}
document.querySelector(".close").onclick = function () {
  document.querySelector(".To-Do").style.display = 'none';
}

document.getElementById("task");
document.getElementById("date");
document.getElementById("tsks");
document.getElementById("check");

document.getElementById("s").onclick = function () {
  var newEl = document.createElement("p");
  newEl.innerHTML = "<input type = 'checkbox'>" + task.value + ' ' + date.value;
  newEl.querySelector("input").addEventListener("click", checked);
  document.getElementById('task2').appendChild(newEl);


}

function checked() {
  if (this.checked) {
    var tsks = this.parentElement;
    tsks.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
    alert("You completed task" + tsks.innerText + "Good Job!");
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/dLrp1gP/43150024-polka-dot-background-blue-vector-elegant-image.jpg");
}

.content {
  background-color: white;
  width: 700px;
  height: 400px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 325px;
  top: 150px;
}

#greet {
  position: absolute;
  left: 445px;
  top: 150px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#2980B9, #6DD5FA, #fff);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

#MyClockDisplay {
  color: blue;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  left: 625px;
  top: 230px;
}

#b {
  background-image: linear-gradient(#2980B9, #6DD5FA, #fff);
  color: black;
  border-color: white;
  text-weight: bold;
  width: 70px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 625px;
  top: 260px;
}

.To-Do {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: none;
  z-index: 1;
}

.modal-content {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: purple;
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 14px;
  font-size: 32px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  cursor: pointer;
}

#aat {
  background-color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}

h2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 590px;
  top: 305px;
  border-bottom: 5px solid blue;
}

p {
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
  left: 590px;
  top: 360px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
<title>To-Do List</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class = "content"></div>
    <div id="MyClockDisplay" class="clock" onload="showTime()"></div>
    <button id = "b">Add A Task</button>
    <div class = "To-Do">
      <div class = "modal-content">
        <h1 align = "center" id = "aat">ADD A TASK</h1>
        <input type = "text" placeholder = "task" id = "task">
        <input type = "date" id = "date">
        <div class = "close">+</div>
        <input type = "submit" id = "s">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id = "task2"></div>
    <h2>YOUR TASKS</h2>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work by changing checked() to window.checked() and removing the if statement in side the checked function

```
newEl.innerHTML =  "<input type = 'checkbox' id = 'check' onclick = 'window.checked()'>"  + task.value  + '&nbsp;' + date.value;
```

```
function checked() {
  tsks.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
  alert("You completed task" + tsks.value + "Good Job!");
}
```

Comment: As others pointed out it'll work as long as you don't call the function checked

Answer (score 1):

Two points:

1. You have used function "checked" on the checkbox. It is the name of
       property, so choose any other name
2. To change only selected
       element - pass it to event handler.

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/zordaxy/L0sbp8mt/27/

```js
document.getElementById("b").onclick = function() {
 document.querySelector(".To-Do").style.display = 'flex';
}
document.querySelector(".close").onclick = function() {
 document.querySelector(".To-Do").style.display = 'none';
}

document.getElementById("s").onclick = function() {
 var newEl = document.createElement("p");
 newEl.setAttribute("id", "tsks" );
     newEl.innerHTML =  "<input type = 'checkbox' id = 'check' onclick = 'checked2(this);'>"  + task.value  + '&nbsp;' + date.value;
 document.getElementById('task2').appendChild(newEl);


}
function checked2(item) {
 console.log(item);
 item.parentElement.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>To-Do List</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class = "content"></div>
<div id="MyClockDisplay" class="clock" onload="showTime()"></div>
    <button id = "b">Add A Task</button>
<div class = "To-Do">
    <div class = "modal-content">
        <p align = "center" id = "aat" onclick='checked()'>ADD A TASK</p>
        <input type = "text" placeholder = "task" id = "task">
        <input type = "date" id = "date">
        <div class = "close">+</div>
        <input type = "submit" id = "s">
    </div>
</div>
<div id = "task2"></div>
<h2>YOUR TASKS</h2>
</body>
</html>
```