# html code working in IE/FireFox but not in chrome

Tags: javascript, html

This is really simple code that I wanted to try and get running because I wanted to learn some JavaScript basics. The code works in Internet Explorer and Firefox but not on chrome. I feel like I must be missing something really stupid.

```js
var frame = 2;
function animate(){

if(frame == 1){
    frame = frame + 1;
    document.getElementById("animate").src = "walking1.png";
}
else if (frame == 2){
    frame = frame + 1;
    document.getElementById("animate").src = "walking2.png";
}
else{
    frame = 1;
    document.getElementById("animate").src = "walking3.png";
}
}
```

```html
<p> clicking the button will change the image.</p>

<img id="animate" src="walking1.png">

<button onclick="animate()">click me to animate</button>
```

the pictures used are saved in the same folder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`animate` is used both as a function name and an id, which cause it to not work in Chrome.

Also, mentioned [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28173800/js-function-named-animate-doesnt-work-in-chrome-but-works-in-ie), a function alone with the name `animate` might also not work in Chrome, based on how it is implemented. (see notes below)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript">
var frame = 2;
function animatee(){

if(frame == 1){
    frame = frame + 1;
    document.getElementById("animate").src = "http://placehold.it/100";
}
else if (frame == 2){
    frame = frame + 1;
    document.getElementById("animate").src = "http://placehold.it/100/f00";
}
else{
    frame = 1;
    document.getElementById("animate").src = "http://placehold.it/100/00f";
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <p> clicking the button will change the image.</p>

  <img id="animate" src="http://placehold.it/100/0f0">

  <button onclick="animatee();">click me to animate</button>

</body>
</html>
```

*Notes:*

An observation made by [guest271314](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2801559/guest271314) shows that if the onclick handler is not attached inline, the issue is not present

```js
window.onload = function() {

  var frame = 2;

  function animate() {
    console.log("animate called")
    if (frame == 1) {
      frame = frame + 1;
      document.getElementById("animatee").src = "http://placehold.it/100x100";
    } else if (frame == 2) {
      frame = frame + 1;
      document.getElementById("animatee").src = "http://placehold.it/200x200";
    } else {
      frame = 1;
      document.getElementById("animatee").src = "http://placehold.it/100/00f";
    }
  }
  
  document.querySelector("button").onclick = animate;
}
```

```html
<p> clicking the button will change the image.</p>

<img id="animatee" src="http://placehold.it/100/0f0">

<button>click me to animate</button>
```

To their defense [Kaiido](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3702797/kaiido) contributed with the specs: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/nav-history-apis.html#named-access-on-the-window-object

[Knu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/248058/knu) contributed with this bug report:https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=11960

Comment: Weird that living specs doesn't tell how to handle this exact case (should a named element overwrite a previously set global variable ?).

Comment: @LGSon, well it's an interesting link too, but OP's problem was a double one, because what you said is also true : https://jsfiddle.net/aagepzyf/ this fiddle works in FF, not in chrome (and I thought playing with "wrap in head/body" would change something in chrome, but it doesn't.)

Comment: To me, this all sounds like a chrome bug : https://jsfiddle.net/aagepzyf/1/ but to their defense, [specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#named-access-on-the-window-object) don't seem to say how it should be handled. (But returning undefined is clearly not the good course of action either :) ) But all this can be avoided by using  eventListeners, or by avoiding unscoped variables, so the dupe is still a correct target.

Comment: @Kaiido https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=11960

Comment: @Kaiido Issue appears to be global event attribute https://jsfiddle.net/aagepzyf/2/

Comment: @LGSon _"a function alone with the name animate will also not work in Chrome"_ When used at `.onclick` function named animate is called without an error, see jsfiddle.

Comment: @guest271314 I will update ... and use your observation in a note as I find it useful, thanks

Comment: @guest271314, Yes, here you're scoping the variable  `animate` into the anonymous function used as `window.onload` handler. So it won't be confused with named elements which should be returned by `window[name_of_namedElement]`. The problem is only with global (window) scoped variable. The thing strange in chrome is that in the HTML event handler, it sets the variable to undefined, while you can still access it by providing exactly  [`window[variableName]`](https://jsfiddle.net/aagepzyf/4/). So I'm rather confident, **this** is a bug in chrome, since it just ignores both.

Comment: But as stated before, and confirmed by @Knu, this is also a quirk in the specs, which just seems to stand from 2012?!